# Pass Value from Controller to View by ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have a controller and I can seem to understand how to pass a parameter to my ActionResult method.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{name}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Project", name = "Search", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is my route. Now in my controller i've created a method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(int Id)
{
    ViewBag.iD = Id;
    return View();
}
```

And in my view

```
<body>
    <div>
        ASDF + @ViewBag.iD
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I pass a value to my iD parameter from Search Action?  It seems whatever I call
`http://localhost:52992/Project/Search/id=2`
or `http://localhost:52992/Project/Search/1`

Both method go into the Search() method, none goes to Search(int iD).

What Am I missing?

Comment: A link makes a GET, not a POST, so your GET method needs to be `public ActionResult Search(int ID)` (and delete the POST method)

Comment: I feel a complete idiot now. Thank you! You can post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A link in your view (or a form with `FormMethod.Get` or entering a url in the address bar) makes a GET call, not a POST, so your method should be

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(int ID)
{
    // do something based on the value of ID
    ViewBag.iD = ID;
    return View();
}
```

and delete the `[HttpPost]` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass value from the `HttpGet` 'SearchAction' method. if you pass from it, then only the value will be shown in the view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search()
{
    ViewBag.iD = your Id value here;
    return View();
}
```

on intial load the get method will be called, on submission only the 'post' method will be call.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On your view

```
<a href='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id= 10})'>...</a>
```

OR

```
 @{ 
int id = 10 
}
    <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/@id"> ... </a>
```

On Your Action

```
Public ActionResult Search(int id)
{
Viewbag.Id = id;
return view();
}
```

Action is by default on [HTTPGET] you wont have to mention it