# How do I add 2 lists of text (ViewBag) in select2 and make them shown separatedly in OptGroup

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery-select2

Let's say I have this in my controller:

```
ViewBag.ListA = list_a;
ViewBag.ListB = list_b;
```

This is my view:

```
         $("#selectForm").select2({
            data: (what to add here?),
            width: '30%',
            allowClear: true,
            placeholder: "Select Form"
         });
```

This is the Razor part:

```
<select id="selectForm" name="inputName" class="form-control inputName"></select>
```

I want the result to look similar to this, except that I want to use the lists passed from controller in ViewBag. Optgroup1 shows data from list_A,  Optgroup2 shows data from list_B:
http://jsfiddle.net/56be9zop/59/

I'm a beginner to asp.net and have spent a very long time googling but could not find the answer. I will appreciate it a lot of anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewBag.ListA` as a variable in your view.
Check this out:
[Pass Value from Controller to View by ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867975/pass-value-from-controller-to-view-by-viewbag)

Comment: I have no problem passing ViewBag from controller to View. The problem is I don't know how to put two ViewBags to a select2 with the options being in groups.